# Users get logged out when they click on a hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, hyperlink, hosting

C# application users gets logged out whenever they click on a hyperlink (not the logout button). The application is tied in with MS Sql closely and whenever the user click link 1, they get logged out from the application, log back in, click link 1 again, and get logged out.

In addition, it is not always the same link. Other times it changes to a different link. Also, it sometimes happen to two users at the same time. Sometimes they both have issue clicking on one of the links. Other times, one have issue with link 1 and another have issue with link 2.

I had all users use CCleaner to clear up all of their cache and what not. It fixes it for an hour or so then it comes back. It also happens in incognito/private mode. Happens on multiple browsers.

The application and database is hosted on Hostgator windows shared server (trying to move out but owner doesn't want to pay the money).

I uploaded the same application to a GoDaddy server and so far so good, minus the constant log out after 10-15 minutes. I haven't heard of anyone getting logged out because they clicked on a hyperlink.

Those links open in the same page. Not a new tab. The database isn't that big. About 2 GB. There are about 400 records in our most used table.

I googled this for few days now and I haven't read of anyone having the exact issue or similar to what I have.

Also, the application have been working well and never experienced this until recently.

Anyone have any idea what's going on? I don't think it is a problem within the application because I didn't make any changes when it comes to sessions. It just started doing it after hostgator server went down last week. I talked with hostgator and they said it is an issue with my cache, which is part of truth.

Comment: How could we possibly help without seeing any code?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I have never done that but I will look into how it is done and learn. Thank you for a good suggestion

Comment: @DavidG I would show the code if it was an issue with a certain page but it isn't. But I do understand that some people cannot help unless they see the code due to their limited experience and knowledge. Thanks for the comment though

Comment: Are you insinuating that I have limited experience and knowledge?

Comment: @ramden glad to hear you had a good breakfast this morning. Going by what you said though, your breakfast was good today but tomorrow might not be the case. Be cautious or the breakfast might break your stomach

Comment: @DavidG absolutely not! I do apologize if it came across that way. I don't know you or how much or long you have worked in development. I really didn't mean anything disrespectful

Comment: Sorry for my comment, my friend was fooling around on my pc

Comment: @ramden all is good! hope your day is full of laughter then!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you got a Serious Problem.

To that link as you've said kindly check the code i suspected it 100% it has an action its either your `session expired`, `directing to other page with session expired` or `logout function called`, or maybe its in your `javascript html` there's various of causes why it is triggering.

Just giving you some possible cases.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Good call but I don't believe that to be the case here. I haven't done any changes to the page and it has been working for the past 4+ months.

But I have suspected that as well and looked anywhere for something like that and it is only being applied to the logout button.

Also, there's no javascript involved.

Comment: Did you check the session if expired or not.. Just check possible cases one by one.

Comment: On my part i never use session anymore.. i fell more comfortable with Cookies not Session.

Comment: As for session expired, I tied to confirm it by displaying a timer or a message before it expire but that never happened or got triggered. As in, the timer will still have time left and the message doesn't get triggered. I researched that and many people who uses hostgator said that they have similar issue due to the nature of hostgator's shard server settings. I will look into cookies more. I

Comment: also, if you any tutorials that helped you with cookies, then I will gladly read or watch them. I am reading more right now

Comment: follow this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx